# Enclosing type behaviour when the enclosing instance is nullified

Tags: java, garbage-collection, inner-classes

I ran the following snippet, which outputted `Hey David`.

```
public class Test {
    public String name;

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public class A {
        public String toString() {
            return "Hey " + name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test("David");
        A a = test.new A();
        test = null;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I also tested to call `System.gc()` before printing `a` but I am not sure it actually triggers immediatly a full GC so it might not be relevant. To be honest, before running the code I had no idea of what it was supposed to happen, because the actual behaviour seems as logical to me as if a NPE had been thrown, since `name` is attached to an instance which is nullified.

Could you explain me why we observe that and how exactly work instances of an enclosing type ?

Comment: If the Java GC is like the .NET GC: setting it to `null` won't make a difference for the GC because of the object lifetime table. And `System.gc()` is not guaranteed to perform a GC. All you do here is point the variable to `null` but that doesn't "remove" the object itself because you don't touch `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An instance is never *nullified*. That is not a concept that exists in Java. What is nullified is the variable, the reference. The `A` instance, however, still has a valid reference to its enclosing instance and can therefore use it.

Comment: I think I understand : I just lost my reference to `test` but the object still exists and is not considered as garbage collectable (if that's the right term) since I still have a valid reference on an enclosing instance. Is that it ?

Comment: @Dici That is correct. You have a reachable reference to it from `a`.

Comment: Well it was in fact a stupid question, thanks anyway ! I'll accept this answer after the 8 minutes delay.